# Advanced Custom Fields - Relationship Field

Tags: php, html, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the relationship field within a custom post type, but my content is not showing up. I have doubled checked against the documentation but I cant see why it wouldn't be working.

Any help would be great!

Documentation here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

My html is:

```
<?php

    // The Query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'top-car'
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


        <?php 
        $posts = get_field('top-cars');
        if( $posts ): ?>



        <ul id="recom">

            <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <li>

                <div class="recom-single">
                    <h2><?php the_field( 'model' ); ?></h2>
                </div>
                <!--Close Recom Single-->

            </li>
            <!--Close First Car-->

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        <!--Close Slider-->

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, we have no cars available at this time, please contact us.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is  your custom field name ? which you want to display .

Comment: Must be a friday thing! I have just double checked my post type name and its an _ rather than a -. Panic over! Thank you for prompting me!